# JSF Changing Css Parts while lifetime

Tags: css, jsf

I was wondering if you can change your style while lifetime?!

Example: Administrtor loggs into the app, chooses interface settings and finally changes the color of the overall header

That would be a nice component to do so: [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/colorPicker.jsf)

So is that possible? And can you give me a little hint how to do that :-)
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I had done this by having multiple css classes predefined and then on the back-end had a variable containing the current class in use.
You can then with an interface or some parameters, or user settings, etc, choose a class to give to the variable.

In my jsp page the code was something like this:

```
<div class="#{logEntry.styleClass}">
```

and the backend variable "styleClass" was of type String.

Comment: nice solution, but then the admin can only choose predefined stuff...hmm... maybe this way is better... let's see what other user suggest